# Problems tabulating a large matrix

Tags: r

I need to generate a table from a very large matrix (17GB, with 2,278,439,289 elements).
The code I want to run is

```
distance_table = table(distance_matrix)
```

However, I always run into the problems of "long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:1121", I guess because I don't have enough memory to run this. Do you know how can i split it up to count the elements of sub-matrix individually?

Comment: is your matrix sparse? [e.g.](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r/)

Comment: No, actually most of the elements are Infinitive

Comment: If you don't have a sparse matrix, ie a matrix where most of the the elements are 0, then you may take a look at working with the `bigmemory` suite of packages.

Comment: thanks. i will try it now. do you know how can i implement it?

Comment: for tabulation, you could easily tabulate individual chunks of the matrix and then merge the tabulations (by summing values across the table).  If you post a *small* reproducible example someone could show you how to do that. (What strategies have you tried yourself so far?) (For `bigmemory`, have you tried googling "bigmemory package CRAN" ?)